# Copy default python module in a separate file and importing the module from new path

Tags: python

I am working on modbus_tk python module. I have a specific requirement where I am changing some classes in the modbus_tk library where it is actually installed in my system and it is working as expected.

As I am running my code on different machines, every time  I have to change the `modbus_tk` library in every machine where i want to run my code

I thought of copying modbus_tk library in same folder as my project so that I do not need to change the code at each machine

My project structure

Test project

```
->__init__.py
-->XYZ.py  (file that is importing modbus_tk)
-->some_other_file.py
-->modbus_tk_directory
-->-->modbus.py
-->-->helper.py
```

In my XYZ.py file here i am using import statement as

```
import modbus_tk
```

But it is still importing from default path that is under site_packages

How to import modbus_tk from customized path

Answer (score 0):

Have you do this:

```
touch modbus_tk/__init__.py
```

And try this:

```
from .modbus_tk import helper, modbus
```